# Copy-Item: A positional parameter cannot be found that accepts argument '+'

Tags: powershell, copy

Can anyone help me with this error? What is wrong in this command line from image?

```
copy /b file.msi + malicious.jar newfile.jar
```

[image: PowerShell Image]

Comment: Please (also) post your code, data, error messages as _text_, [not as _images_](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/45375).

Comment: Welcome to SO. Please take a little time to do the [Tour] and read at least the help topic [Ask] .... and please do not post [pictures of code](https://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode) as this is not helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to use `cmd.exe`'s `copy` command, which is an *internal* command to `cmd.exe` (not a separate executable). As such, you can only call it via `cmd /c` from PowerShell.

By contrast, `copy`, when called directly from PowerShell, is a built-in [alias](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Aliases) that refers to PowerShell's [`Copy-Item`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/copy-item) cmdlet, whose invocation syntax and supported parameters differ fundamentally from `cmd.exe`'s internal `copy` command.

`Copy-Item` does *not* support *merging* multiple files (`+`) as *binary* files (`/b`), so you'll have to call `cmd.exe`'s `copy` command, via `cmd /c`:

```
cmd /c 'copy /b file.msi + malicious.jar newfile.jar'
```